# Powershell and some simple string manipulation

Tags: string, powershell

need some help with building a powershell script to help with some basic string manipulation.  I know just enough powershell to get in trouble, but can't figure out the syntax or coding to make this work.

I have a text file that looks like this -

```
Here is your list of servers:
server1
server2.domain.local
server3
Total number of servers: 3
```

I need to take that text file and drop the first and last lines (Always first and last.)  Then I need to take every other line and basically turn it into a CSV file.

The final output should be a text file that looks like this -

```
server1,server2.domain.local,server3
```

Any suggestions on where to start?  Thanks!

Comment: Wish I could accept all three - all three were helpful and each worked in their own way.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
$a = Get-Content C:\temp\M.TXT # Where M.TXT is your original file
$a[1..($a.count-2)] | % {$s=""} {$s+=$_+","}{$s.trim(",") | Out-File m.csv} # M.CSV is the result file
```

Comment: Close - works perfect, other than we still have the last line "Total number of servers: 3" in the output.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JPBlanc, I suspect his file as an additional blank line at the end of the file.

Comment: Looks like that might be it.  I just changed the count-2 to count-3.  This worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @KeithHill you are right, I just not think about that at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of other ways.

```
(Get-Content foo.txt | Where {$_ -notmatch '^\s*$'} | Select -Skip 1 | 
     Select -Skip 1 -Last 2E9) -join ',' > foo.csv
```

And if you happen to have the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) (for Skip-Object):

```
(Get-Content foo.txt | Where {$_ -notmatch '^\s*$'} | 
     Skip-Object -First 1 -Last 1) -join ',' > foo.csv
```

Note that the `Where {$_ -notmatch '^\s*$'}` eliminates any blank lines.

Comment: Close - the first method works, other than we still have the last line "Total number of servers: 3" in the output.  The second select -skip statment, which has the last 2e9 (What does that mean, anyway?) - are you trying to use that to skip the last line?

Comment: @Pat I believe the `-Skip/-Last` parameter combo might be new in PowerShell v3.  You can skip from the end of the file contents if you use `-Skip` in conjunction with `-Last` but in this case you want all of the lines.  That's why I specify a large number `2E9` for the Last parameter - to get all the lines in the file except for the 1 skipped line at the end.

Comment: On the second skip 1 statement - I changed it to skip 2 and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the range operator:

```
$content = Get-Content D:\Scripts\Temp\test1.txt
$content[1..($content.count-2)] -join ',' | Out-File servers.txt
```

It would be better to export to a csv file so you can import it back and operate on the server names:

```
$content = Get-Content D:\Scripts\Temp\test1.txt
$content[1..($content.count-2)] | Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';e={$_}} | Export-Csv servers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This approach won't work if there are any blank lines at the end of the file (or at the beginning or anywhere in between).

Comment: I imagine the count-3 would work here as well if there's a blank line.  Thanks!